# what problem should/can I solve first?

Tags: installation, command-line, 13.04, shutdown

I am currently running Ubuntu 13.04 x64 with brand new hard drive to replace a damaged component, on my 17.5 inch wide screen gateway laptop with mostly after market components. can not remember the exact specs, it was a gift.
list of problems in inverse order of calamity.

-the only **aspect ratio** choice is 1024 x 720 (4:3) and it gives me a head ache.

-**frame rate** locked at 30 when my refresh rate is 120.

-**performance** all proses are running really slow even mouse movements.

-**unable to install new applications** like SDKs that I was looking forward too because .exe (among most other file types) files are not recognised even after hitting the check box for running code in the selected file or using command line prompts.

-**Alt+F2 command line** codes seem to have **no effect** no matter what I do with it. (may be user error and could use a link to an explanation of how to use it. but copy, past, enter or double click only seems to close the command line.)

-**unable to shut down or restart**, the first time I tried to turn it off after installing 13.04 it displayed text on screen about what it was doing. *halting system/ubuntu.iso [Failed]* and then a few lines latter *running C::/system/path I can not remember/halt /halt not found* I waited 10 minuets then hit Ctrl+Alt+Del and then about 20 secants latter I got */DEbg not found.* followed by *running "same path as for halt"/restart /restart not found*. solved by hard boot. sense then it just goes to black light screen at full brightness, and proceeds to over heat. the good news is that suspend works as intended.

-attempting to **install an earlier stable version of Ubuntu failed** even following the directions given on the site or in forums, but perhaps due to other above problems. when I completed all the steps the frames closed and no changes had taken place or further actions like restarting accrued. the system still says it is running 13.04

-the **problem that exist between chair and key board** is having difficulty finding where to start in the operations manual. at least opening and using default applications works even if slowly. please tell me where I can find what more information is needed, if any.

**TL:DR "panic. panic. panic. it is broken. where do I start? and how?"**

Comment: Tried installing 12.04 LTS x64, it seamed to work~ish but I am somehow still running a buggy 13.04. Was rather tired when I did it so I am not sure what I did. I can not find evidence that it was done other then that the usb stick has all these files on it, but booting from the usb just give a black screen now.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried running 12.04 LTS (Long Term Support...until 2017) via Live CD/DVD? and play with it for a while to see any strange behaviour in your system (if any)...or if your really need 13.04 then tried burning a new iso...

Your problems seem quite interesting, I would recommend a NEW clean installation period.

Good luck,

Luis